# Route 53 Alias record not pointing to S3 static hosted website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, hosting, amazon-route53

I have bought a domain [sandesh.link](http://sandesh.link) from route 53, created a publicly accessible S3 bucket with the same name, created a hosted zone and created an alias record pointing to the S3 static hosted website.

When accessing the domain, it shows that the domain is still parked at gandi.

I have updated the nameservers of the domain to the ones given in the hosted zone nameservers(can be seen at whois). I've also verified the domain through email.

How can I get this working?

Comment: If you run DIG does it resolve your AWS Route 53 name servers? If so it could be that that the NS records have a longer TTL so you would need to wait for it to expire before everyone is resolving to Route 53.

Comment: The domain shows `Welcome folks Welcome`. Is that correct?

Comment: Oh, it does? It still shows the parked page on mine. But if it does, thats what I was trying to do.

Comment: Yes, it works. Maybe you are loading website from local cache?

Comment: Well, I tried clearing all cache, but its still same

Comment: Its working now. Thanks

Comment: If you don't mind, I can provide answer just to finish the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The domain provided, when tested worked fine. It correctly showed:

```
Welcome folks Welcome
```

The reason it did not work before, could be that DNS changes were not fully propagated.